# Tag renaming: censored-user --> censorship

Tags: discussion, tags

Within the main site there is the tag [censored-user](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censored-user). I think a better and more general term for it is [censorship](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship). What do you think about renaming this tag?

Comment: Hi, can you add backtilts on the `censorship` ?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, I think your idea is good - this tag should be renamed.** You're true - new name is most general than [censored-user](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censored-user). I'll retag tagged by this tag questions in a few minutes.

Comment: http://tor.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/245 - Retagged

Comment: Dont retag questions through suggested edits. A retag is a very minor change and will almost always be rejected. Suggested edits are meant to be for significant improvements that improve on multiple aspects of the post. Retags should be done mostly by users who have the editing privileges(>1k).